# How to set --enable-post-process-file in openapi-generator CLI for c++ CPP_POST_PROCESS_FILE

Tags: openapi-generator

I got the following messages every time i generate c++ client from [openapi-generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/usage/#generate):

```
[main] INFO  o.o.c.languages.AbstractCppCodegen - Environment variable CPP_POST_PROCESS_FILE not defined so the C++ code may not be properly formatted. To define it, try 'export CPP_POST_PROCESS_FILE="/usr/local/bin/clang-format -i"' (Linux/Mac)
[main] INFO  o.o.c.languages.AbstractCppCodegen - NOTE: To enable file post-processing, 'enablePostProcessFile' must be set to `true` (--enable-post-process-file for CLI).

[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - The value (generator's option) must be either boolean or string. Default to `false`.
```

I used the following command to run the generator:

```
npx openapi-generator generate -i api.yaml -g cpp-restsdk -o  %CD%
```

How can I fix these messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `npx @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli` instead as https://www.npmjs.com/package/@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli is the official repo of the npm wrapper for openapi-generator.

To enable post file processing, please add `--enable-post-process-file` to the command, e.g.

```
export CPP_POST_PROCESS_FILE="/usr/local/bin/clang-format -i"
npx @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate -i api.yaml -g cpp-restsdk -o  %CD% --enable-post-process-file
```

Comment: thanks, I installed clang-format and used set command instead of export. it worked. however, can u also tell me how to fix  [main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - The value (generator's option)

Comment: Please open an issue via https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/new/ so that the community can help you out.

Comment: How would I maintain that property (enablePostProcessFile) in a maven plugin config XML?